# Xypic Diagram with MnSymbol Arrows

Tags: packages, arrows, xy-pic, mnsymbol

When I use the `MnSymbol` package, I get the usual short arrows, but this is not the case for `xypic` diagrams. Having the following packages

```
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

I have results like in this picture where the different arrow styles is shown:

[image]

**Is there any way to fix this problem?** Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: No, Xy-pic only gives the default (ugly) arrowheads or the `cmtip` ones. One *might* define other arrowheads, but …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining new arrow tips with Xy-pic is a task I'd not engage in.

You can (and should, in my opinion) switch to `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}

\begin{document}
$A \to B$

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[dr,dashed,swap,"g\circ f"] & B \arrow[d,"g"] \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make fine adjustments with `tikz-cd`? (E.g., raising the arrow just `.1pt`)

Comment: @egreg Seems really the best choice, but I have some problems with `tikz-cd`: I get always the message `! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.` What should I change?

Comment: @Jjm Try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`

Comment: @egreg Yes, it works! Now, only one question, just curious... the arrows seem somehow broken when viewed in pdf. I suppose that for a printed document it will be no problem, but for reading in the screen, it is a bit annoying. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @Jjm I guess one has to fix the arrow stem; sorry, but it's beyond my knowledge of TikZ.

Comment: The arrow tips and stems *are* preciously aligned. The apparent misalignment is a rendering artifact -- probably something related to hinting. As far as I know there is not much that can be done about it (except changing to a higher resolution screen and/or better PDF viewer), but it would be really great if somebody proposes a solution.